# Kendo UI datepicker with Angular JS and Require

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker, requirejs

I'm trying to use the Kendo UI datepicker for the register form in an app using Angular JS. All the files seem to be loading correctly however nothing is happening.

To load the library I'm doing the following:

main.js (main require file)

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | RequireJS app configuration
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Loads the app and config
 |
 */

require([
    'libraries'
], function () {

    'use strict';

    require([
        'appBootstrap/app'
    ], function () {

    });

});
```

The libraries file contains the list of third party libs and dependencies:

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | RequireJS external libraries
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Add all third party libraries in here.
 |
 */

require.config({

    baseUrl : 'js/',

    paths : {
    angular       : '../../vendor/angular/angular.min',
    ngAMD         : '../../vendor/angularAMD/angularAMD.min',
    jquery        : '../../vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    kendoUI       : '../../vendor/kendo-ui-core/js/kendo.angular.min'
},

shim : {
    app : {
        deps : ['angular', 'jquery']
    },
    ngAMD : {
        deps : ['angular']
    },
    kendoUI : {
        deps : ['angular', 'jquery']
    }
},

deps: ['appBootstrap/app']

});
```

And finally, I tell the app to import kendo ui directives:

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | RequireJS application
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Loads the different application elements.
 | Controllers, Models, Directives, Services, Factories...
 |
 */

define([
    'ngAMD',
    'kendoUI',
    'jquery'
], function (config, angularAMD) {

    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('appModule', [
        'kendo.directives'
    ]);

    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

});
```

In the controller if the page, I've included the path of the datepicker directive:

```
define([
    'appBootstrap/app',
    '../../vendor/kendo-ui-core/js/kendo.datepicker.min',
    'services/accountsService'
], function (app) {

    'use strict';

    app.controller('RegisterPlinkerController', function ($scope, $location, $timeout, accountsService) {

        ...

    });

});
```

And in the view, I've added a datepicker:

```
<input class="form-control"
       name="date_of_birth"
       id="date_of_birth"
       kendo-date-picker
       ng-model="register.date_of_birth"
       k-ng-model="dateObject">
```

Why is the datepicker field not doing anything (apart from showing a standard text field)?

Please can seombody help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that **dateObject** is Date type, close the tag and include all the css and js files:

```
<input kendo-date-picker k-ng-model="dateObject" />

kendo.common.min.css
kendo.common-material.min.css
kendo.default.min.css
kendo.material.min.css
```

Kendo override ng-mode by **k-ng-mode** that provide an date type object.

Maybe you need to include de kendo.core.js or try with kendo.all.js.